# How to find duplicates OK indexes in Access application?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have this code that lists all indexes, but I only need those where Indexed: *"Yes, duplicates OK"* is set. Is there any way to do that instead of manually look through all indexes? I need to migrate the data to SQL Server, but with this I only get empty tables in SQL Server.

```
Const adSchemaIndexes As Long = 12
Dim cn As Object ' ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As Object ' ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Long

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaIndexes)
With rs
    ' enable next three lines to view all the recordset column names
'    For i = 0 To (.Fields.Count - 1)
'        Debug.Print .Fields(i).Name
'    Next i
    Do While Not .EOF
       Debug.Print !TABLE_NAME, !INDEX_NAME, !PRIMARY_KEY
       .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, that procedure displays only 3 of the recordset's 25 columns.  If you follow the comment instruction to *"enable next three lines"*, you can view the names of all the available columns.  One column in particular (`UNIQUE`) should be useful for your purpose.  When you choose *"Yes (Duplicates OK)"* for the *"Indexed"* property in table design, it will be displayed as False in the `UNIQUE` column of the schema recordset.

I assumed you're not interested in information for indexes on system tables (*"MSys*"* table names).  And, for the non-system table indexes, only present information for those without a unique constraint.  Here is how I modified the `Do While` loop accordingly:

```vb
Do While Not .EOF
    If !Unique = False And Not !TABLE_NAME Like "MSys*" Then
        Debug.Print !TABLE_NAME, !INDEX_NAME, !COLUMN_NAME, !Unique
   End If
   .MoveNext
Loop
```

Here is the output from the revised procedure in my test database:

```
DiscardMe     compound_4_5  f4            False
DiscardMe     compound_4_5  f5            False
DiscardMe     f3            f3            False
```

That table has 2 non-unique indexes.  One of them is a compound index, based on 2 fields.  So the schema recordset includes separate rows for each of those fields. The other index is based on a single field, so is presented as a single row in the recordset.

I think that gives you what your question asks for.  But I have no idea how those indexes would interfere with migrating your table data to SQL Server.  Good luck.